# Always redirected to root folder when accessing AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

So I'm trying to run my angularJS app on the linux server, and when I access any url different from / the page is redirected to /, my config for nginx is:

```
server {
  server_name localhost;

  root /var/www/myproject/public;

  index index.html;

  location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)$ {
  }

  location / {
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    expires -1;
    add_header Pragma "no-cache";
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

Just a fyi my app just doesn't make requests, just load a local json and navigate using #/page-name(the url is not going to nowhere, angular just use this to render templates in html, this templates is already inside html), nginx need config for accept urls with "#"? any config wrong in this snippet?

Comment: If you are indeed experiencing that `any url different from / the page is redirected to /` then the config you posted is not the one handling your website.

Comment: @Dayo this is the conf file that is working on, please take a look at my nginx.conf file(that imports this snippet that I've posted) https://gist.github.com/WagnerMoreira/aa3effe01c94fb971d33 and inside conf.d folder just exists this snippet that I've posted, should have something wrong in nginx.conf

Comment: The config looks OK which would suggest this issue is not with Nginx. You might want to take a closer look at your AngularJS app perhaps.

Comment: @Dayo you are right, this problem occurs because the hashbang in URL's, so I changed the angular router to use  ```$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');``` and it works

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

and this way I'm able to use routes without '#' :D